# Retrieving userdata directly after user completes acount linking on their phone

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm building an application using Accountlinking for a **Google Home speaker** using the Actions On Google SDK. I am using the [Oauth](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in-oauth?creation=no&oauth=code) feature which allows a user to sign-in into an account on their phone by sending them a link with a login window.

[image]

When the sign-in is triggered, the conversation on the Google speaker is ended. I would like to use some user information that comes from the accountlinking process right after the user is done with the accountlinking.

When you build a conversation for assistant on mobile, you can await the **actions.intent.SIGN_IN** event to continue the conversation, but even when you implement this, a conversation for the speaker will end.

> Is there any way to use user information directly after a user linked
>   their account for a Google Home speaker app without users having to restart the conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the user has to jump to the phone to perform account linking, the conversation on the speaker ends since the context has shifted devices. After account linking finishes, you could try to [transfer to a new surface](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities#multi-surface_conversations), although you will not necessarily have the ability to go back to the original device.

Comment: Since the conversation ends after triggering accountlinking, should i attempt to transfer to a new surface after the acountlinking trigger  or should i transfer it to a new surface first and then trigger the acount linking?

Comment: If you account link on a phone, I'm pretty sure the conversation does continue. You may want to throw it to the phone first, before you do the account linking.